# In MediaWiki how to display external data inline?

Tags: mediawiki

In a MediaWiki wiki how to display external data inline? For example in a table of comparisons to include prices, where the prices are fetched from other sites which are independent of the wiki.

Comment: You tagged this question with [tag:semantic-web], which refers to the *Semantic Web* (i.e., RDF, URIs, SPARQL, Linked Data etc.), but your question doesn’t mention any related concept.

Comment: @unor we need a [semantic-mediawiki] tag as used on other SE sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **External Data extension** for MediaWiki. This will pull data as CSV, GFF, JSON or XML, or LDAP server or database, which can then be displayed on the page.

> The External Data extension allows MediaWiki pages to retrieve, filter, and format structured data from one or more sources. These sources can include external URLs, regular wiki pages, uploaded files, files on the local server, databases or LDAP directories.

For more information, see the extension page:

- http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:External_Data